# Table Filter in NG-ZORRO

Tags: angular11, ng-zorro-antd

I am using nz-table component of NG-ZORRO in my angular 11 App. I want instant search functionality when user type in the textbox.
[image: Here] Here is UI where I used the nz-table

I know there is column level filter option in NG-ZORRO as per their [documentation](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#components-table-demo-head) .

But didn't find the functionality like this what I am looking for.
Any idea if there is way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the filter property (nzFilterChange) on your th tag. For example :

```js
filterChange(search: string) {
  // You can do the job here
}
```

```html
<th (nzFilterChange)="filterChange($event)">Header</th>
```